# How to use keys and values in foreach using php?

Tags: php

I am having the following friendDetails array output,

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => Aruun
            [last_name] => Sukumar
            [photo] => jpg
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [first_name] => senthilkumar
        [last_name] => Kumar
        [photo] => jpg
    )
```

)
I use the following piece of code to to get final output

```
  foreach($friendDetails as $value){
       array_push($friendList, $value[id].".".$value[photo]."-".$value[first_name]." ".$value[last_name]);
  }
```

Final  output will be,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.jpg-Aruun Sukumar
    [1] => 2.jpg-senthilkumar Kumar
    [2] => 18.jpg-senthilkumar sugumar
)
```

Here I am getting Notice Error with exact output. What i done wrong on the code?
Is there any other way to get Final Output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the notice error as you are not putting the keys of your array in quotes.

It should be:

```
foreach($friendDetails as $value){                       
    array_push($friendList, $value['id'].".".$value['photo']."-".$value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name']);                    
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around your key identifiers:

```
$value['id'] . "." . $value['photo']
```

etc. See "Why is $foo[bar] wrong?" at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this you will get both key and value:

```
  foreach ($friendDetails as $key_name => $key_value) {
   print "Key = " . $key_name . " Value = " . $key_value . "<BR>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You need to put quotes (") around the array keys in the `array_push` (i.e. `$value["id"]`)
- Make sure that you define `$friendList` as an array before the `foreach`.

A working example:

```
<?php

$friendDetails = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'first_name' => 'Aruun',
    'last_name' => 'Sukumar',
    'photo' => 'jpg'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'first_name' => 'senthilkumar',
    'last_name' => 'Kumar',
    'photo' => 'jpg'
  )
);

$friendList = array();

foreach($friendDetails as $value){                       
 array_push($friendList, $value["id"].".".$value["photo"]."-".$value["first_name"]." ".$value["last_name"]);                    
}

print_r($friendList);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotations around your array values:

```
foreach($friendDetails as $value){                         
   array_push($friendList, $value['id'].".".$value['photo']."-".$value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name']);                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$friendList = array();    
foreach($friendDetails as $key=> $value){                       
        $friendList[] =  $value['id'].".".$value['photo']."-".$value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name']);                    
    }
```